# Creating an attribute and trying to follow best practices

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm creating a custom attribute and trying to follow best practices.  I looked at class `SysObsoleteAttribute` for an example, and can anybody explain the reasoning behind the methods they chose to create?  It seems almost random and counter-intuitive.

The attribute holds two variables, `explanation`(str) and `isError`(boolean).

They created a parm method `parmExplanation` that just returns the `explanation` but doesn't allow you to set by calling the **protected** `Explanation` method.

They then create a **public** `isError` method to access the `isError` variable?

Is there any rhyme or reason to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating parm methods without arguments is not best practice!

I guess the answer to your question is no.

This specific attricbute class [SysObsoleteAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg864301.aspx) is called from the compiler, so improving upon it may be difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the second set of eyes.  I'm trying to write beautiful/perfect code and thought I'd look to Microsoft for an example...definitely didn't see what I'd hoped for, HA

Comment: Be prepared for tons of sloppy code and bad style in standard code.